# JavaScript Live Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm trying to make a live calculator in java script and html and by live I mean every time a number or a symbol changes the answer changes live time. So I wrote this code but every time I change the number or symbol the answer just goes away.

I tried to to change the if statements to be more direct with the imports from the html file but that still didn't work.

```js
var num01 = document.getElementById("num01").value;
var num02 = document.getElementById("num02").value;
var calculation = document.getElementById("calculation");
var answer = document.getElementById("answer");

calculation.onchange = function() {
  calculationSelect = this.value
  if (calculationSelect = "") {
    answer.innerText = "0"
  } else if (calculationSelect = "+") {
    answer.innerText = num01 + num02
  } else if (calculationSelect = "-") {
    answer.innerText = num01 - num02
  } else if (calculationSelect = "x") {
    answer.innerText = num01 * num02
  } else if (calculationSelect = "/") {
    answer.innerText = num01 / num02
  }
}

document.getElementById("num01").onchange = function() {
  if (calculationSelect = "") {
    answer.innerText = "0"
  } else if (calculationSelect = "+") {
    answer.innerText = num01 + num02
  } else if (calculationSelect = "-") {
    answer.innerText = num01 - num02
  } else if (calculationSelect = "x") {
    answer.innerText = num01 * num02
  } else if (calculationSelect = "/") {
    answer.innerText = num01 / num02
  }
}

document.getElementById("num02").onchange = function() {
  if (calculationSelect = "") {
    answer.innerText = "0"
  } else if (calculationSelect = "+") {
    answer.innerText = num01 + num02
  } else if (calculationSelect = "-") {
    answer.innerText = num01 - num02
  } else if (calculationSelect = "x") {
    answer.innerText = num01 * num02
  } else if (calculationSelect = "/") {
    answer.innerText = num01 / num02
  }
}
```

```css
#answer {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label id="answer">0</label>
<input type="number" id="num01">
<select id="calculation">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="+">+</option>
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="x">x</option>
  <option value="/">/</option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="num02">
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to get the values every time something changes, not just when loading the page. Also the `=` is an assignment, not a comparison. See the dupe.
[Here is a more streamlined version with error checking](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qm98dj0b/)